# Get the polygon of overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, html, polygon

How can I get the polygon (point1x point1y, point2x point2y, point3x point3y...) of three overlapping divs? The divs are rotated so the polygon is not a rect. Check the 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lgff6qv9/

```
<div class="rect red"></div>
<div class="rect green"></div>
<div class="rect blue"></div>
```

I want the polygon of the deep purple area. Of course in JavaScript :-)

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I think that's going to be amazingly difficult, probably more so than you think. Maybe using a canvas and knowing the colors, one could get the pixels etc. In the DOM I think it's going to be next to impossible, but maybe someone has a clever idea.

Comment: @adeneo, I used the color only for the demo. After having the polygon I want to pass it to a CSS clip-path property.

Comment: @j08691, when I have something ready I will update the fiddle.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/

Comment: @AngusJohnson the jsclipper seems promising but it seems that can only be applied to svg objects. I will check if I can use it at divs.

Comment: I assume extracting the vertices of the divs individually is not acceptable. http://jsfiddle.net/Lgff6qv9/2/

Comment: @user985409, Well, actually you could obtain the polygons with plain math. Just recreate the CSS transformations. But depending on your problem that's not a solution. Probing the vertices with a temporary DOM element is a bit DOM heavy. Infact I was a bit surprised that it works so smoothly, even when you animate to the divs. You could reduce the amount of measurements depending on the type of transformation. But still it feels like a bad hack. There *should* be a native API to obtain the bounding polygon.